# How to install SAN SLL certificat on II7?

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

How do I install the SSL certificate on IIS7?

I have an SSL certificate with two domains :

- *.example.net
- www.example.com.

These two domains work on the same IP.

But when I try to access https://www.a.example.net, I am redirected to https://www.example.net.

Before installing this certificate, everything worked.

Are there parameters to set with the SAN certificate in IIS 7?

Comment: Merely installing the certificate won't add redirection like that. It is time to check what exactly you have changed and where the redirection comes from.

Answer (score -1):

The installation of an SSL Certificate on IIS7 requires technical knowledge to complete...try [these services](http://ssladvice.com/the-best-ssl-certificate-installation-services-on-the-web/),maybe can help.